# Different price for each region

Tags: magento-1.7

My client wants to have specific prices for products according to a country ,moreover prices must be in user's local currency

whats should be the solution of this problem as currently the store is ready with 10000 products.

i thought that first we check incoming user ip to detect country and according to that we set users base currency ,but how could i show him specific prices according to selected country ?

***for example a product which is priced 100 INR in India should be 150 INR for USA and that 150 INR should be shown in Dollars's  ,So price should be 3$ in USA***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer chosen does not answer the question fully, it answers it from a technical perspective but not from a business or combined business/technical view which is actually what 80% of the question is. Selling a product in USA but checkout in non-USD means virtually no exposure in the US market, the majority will not buy. For that you need multiple base currencies to allow local currency checkout but then you need to update each base currency amount for each product manually, on currency exchange updates you also need to update each, so with 4 checkout currencies you need to update 30-40,000 times per day (depending on source product currency). This is just the simple problem, then you have delivery duty paid/unpaid prices, import duties, cogs, so short term the answer looks to be correct, but medium to long term the whole business infrastructure will collapse for international sales, they will have a technical solution but it will not generate any substantial extra revenue as you need the all the other pricing functionality. Look at the top international retailers, that is how it should be done, and we know of only one company who has succeeded to make Magento work like this, everything else provides marginal gains.

Comment: The website pricing is based on question: Is it india or outsite India?
so for outside india we will have another store with different pricing , and to keep base currency local to respective country we will do so detecting geoip and magento will automatically convert the store prices to selected base currency.
and base currency conversion rates can be synced hourly

Comment: now i get your whole point (after 3 weeks)
could you elaborate little more
`Look at the top international retailers, that is how it should be done only one company who has succeeded to make Magento work like this`

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple:

- Create a new store view
- Configure this store view to have a different locale, currency
- Set up a rate of exchange in `System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup`

The store view switcher should appear outside of single-store mode - though your theme will have to provide the ability to display it. Switching stores will affect the display of the new currency/price.

Best of luck!

Comment: So you are saying that i should create a 2nd store and set its base currency and locale **But what about the Prices?**

Does in 2nd store i can change the change the prices of all products and the prices on my first store would not be affected.

Comment: Correct, when managing products in the catalog admin area you will have a dropdown in the top left that will allow you to change which store/view you're editing the price for.

Comment: Wow that's cool and lots of thanks ,But how i can view my 2nd store view ,so that i can code like  `if country is USA go to second.store.view`

Comment: There are a number of Geocode plugins. Search magento connect or elsewhere. This is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Not able to see any option to change the price/store-view. Your answer is wrong

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. Why don't you find the answer yourself, then, and post it? @PankajUpadhyay

Comment: @philwinkle pricing can only be changed at website level and not store/store-view level unless someone uses an extension.